Installing UAD Drivers "Error 0x80070643: Failed to execute MSI package"
I've been trying to install UAD Drivers for Apollo Solo USB interface but I can't fix this problem and the support doesn't answer. I guess it has to be with something Windows-related but after many tries in different ways I don't know what else to do :(
I will let log here
[3028:3034][2024-05-31T01:31:33]i319: Applied execute package: Install64Bit, result: 0x0, restart: None
[2FA4:2F64][2024-05-31T01:31:33]i325: Registering dependency: {dc4a9c8c-f4dc-4396-9ec4-dae31d5532ac} on package provider: {3129E8F0-D71F-44CA-AD8C-22261CC4D96F}, package: Install64Bit
[2FA4:2F64][2024-05-31T01:31:33]i323: Registering package dependency provider: {98836933-1A01-4652-AFD2-FBC978A93D58}, version: 11.1.0.40597, package: InstallVST364Bit
[2FA4:2F64][2024-05-31T01:31:33]i325: Registering dependency: {dc4a9c8c-f4dc-4396-9ec4-dae31d5532ac} on package provider: {98836933-1A01-4652-AFD2-FBC978A93D58}, package: InstallVST364Bit
[2FA4:2F64][2024-05-31T01:31:33]i323: Registering package dependency provider: {B4C376F1-3A9B-4469-B914-D37538D91B9C}, version: 11.1.0.40597, package: InstallApollo32
[2FA4:2F64][2024-05-31T01:31:33]i301: Applying execute package: InstallApollo32, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{B4C376F1-3A9B-4469-B914-D37538D91B9C}v11.1.0.40597\apollo-32bit.msi, arguments: ' ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT="1" MSIFASTINSTALL="7" UA_INSTALLDIR="C:\Program Files (x86)\Universal Audio\Powered Plugins\" ADDLOCAL="" APOLLO_PREVIOUSLY_INSTALLED=""'
**[2FA4:2F64][2024-05-31T01:31:49]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to install MSI package.
[2FA4:2F64][2024-05-31T01:31:49]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to execute MSI package.
[3028:3034][2024-05-31T01:31:49]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to configure per-machine MSI package.
[3028:3034][2024-05-31T01:31:49]i319: Applied execute package: InstallApollo32, result: 0x80070643, restart: None
[3028:3034][2024-05-31T01:31:49]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to execute MSI package.**
[2FA4:2F64][2024-05-31T01:31:49]i301: Applying rollback package: InstallApollo32, action: Uninstall, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{B4C376F1-3A9B-4469-B914-D37538D91B9C}v11.1.0.40597\apollo-32bit.msi, arguments: ' ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT="1" MSIFASTINSTALL="7" UA_INSTALLDIR="C:\Program Files (x86)\Universal Audio\Powered Plugins\" ADDLOCAL="" APOLLO_PREVIOUSLY_INSTALLED=""'
[3028:3034][2024-05-31T01:31:53]i319: Applied rollback package: InstallApollo32, result: 0x0, restart: None
[2FA4:2F64][2024-05-31T01:31:53]i329: Removed package dependency provider: {B4C376F1-3A9B-4469-B914-D37538D91B9C}, package: InstallApollo32
[2FA4:2F64][2024-05-31T01:31:53]i351: Removing cached package: InstallApollo32, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{B4C376F1-3A9B-4469-B914-D37538D91B9C}v11.1.0.40597\
[2FA4:2F64][2024-05-31T01:31:53]i326: Removed dependency: {dc4a9c8c-f4dc-4396-9ec4-dae31d5532ac} on package provider: {98836933-1A01-4652-AFD2-FBC978A93D58}, package InstallVST364Bit
[2FA4:2F64][2024-05-31T01:31:53]i329: Removed package dependency provider: {98836933-1A01-4652-AFD2-FBC978A93D58}, package: InstallVST364Bit
[2FA4:2F64][2024-05-31T01:31:53]i326: Removed dependency: {dc4a9c8c-f4dc-4396-9ec4-dae31d5532ac} on package provider: {3129E8F0-D71F-44CA-AD8C-22261CC4D96F}, package Install64Bit
[2FA4:2F64][2024-05-31T01:31:53]i301: Applying rollback package: Install64Bit, action: Uninstall, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{3129E8F0-D71F-44CA-AD8C-22261CC4D96F}v11.1.0.40597\Data\plugins-64bit.msi, arguments: ' ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT="1" MSIFASTINSTALL="7" UA_INSTALLDIR="C:\Program Files (x86)\Universal Audio\Powered Plugins\"'
[3028:3034][2024-05-31T01:32:05]i319: Applied rollback package: Install64Bit, result: 0x0, restart: None
[2FA4:2F64][2024-05-31T01:32:05]i329: Removed package dependency provider: {3129E8F0-D71F-44CA-AD8C-22261CC4D96F}, package: Install64Bit
[2FA4:2F64][2024-05-31T01:32:05]i351: Removing cached package: Install64Bit, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{3129E8F0-D71F-44CA-AD8C-22261CC4D96F}v11.1.0.40597\
[2FA4:2F64][2024-05-31T01:32:05]i326: Removed dependency: {dc4a9c8c-f4dc-4396-9ec4-dae31d5532ac} on package provider: {C6E59DB6-635A-45B3-8AF7-B2A723848DBE}, package RunDPInst

I've tried fixing Windows registry, updating C++ and .NET, throwing scf and some /scanhealth related into CMD, also tried with previous versions of these drivers but none of them seems to work.

Your question is off-topic. You have better chances for advice e.g. on these platforms: https://superuser.com/ OR https://sound.stackexchange.com/
